# Why is this Python function to sort integers contained as strings slower than this?

Tags: python, performance, sorting, profiling, reasoning

I have two python functions for sorting a list of integers contained as strings. They are follows:

```
import random

n = 10000000
unsorted = [str(x) for x in range(n)]
random.shuffle(unsorted)

def sort_alg1(unsorted):
    unsorted.sort(key = lambda x: int(x))
    return unsorted

def sort_alg2(unsorted):
    l=list(map(int,unsorted))
    l.sort()
    s=list(map(str,l))
    return s

print(sort_alg1(unsorted))
print(sort_alg2(unsorted))
```

Both work as expected. However, according to my profiler (I am using the ever-popular [line_profiler](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler) by Robert Kern), the first function i.e. `sort_alg1` is more than 3 times slower in execution as `sort_alg2`. Now that wouldn't be a big problem if I could pinpoint the reason for this, but I am unable to. I have tried looking up differences in the built-in `sort()` method and `map()` function, lambda, etc. all to no avail. If someone could educate me as to why this is happening, that would be really great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing some benchmark:

```py
from timeit import timeit
import random

n = 1_000_000
unsorted = [str(x) for x in range(n)]
random.shuffle(unsorted)


def sort_alg1(unsorted):
    unsorted.sort(key=lambda x: int(x))
    return unsorted


def sort_alg2(unsorted):
    l = list(map(int, unsorted))
    l.sort()
    s = list(map(str, l))
    return s


t1 = timeit(lambda: sort_alg1(unsorted), number=1)
t2 = timeit(lambda: sort_alg2(unsorted), number=1)

print(t1)
print(t2)
```

Prints:

```
0.4568827738985419
0.2486396620515734
```

So it seems that `sort_alg2` is faster. But the reason is that `sort_alg2` receives already sorted array from `sort_alg1`. If you slightly change the benchmark:

```py
t1 = timeit(lambda: sort_alg1(unsorted), number=1)
random.shuffle(unsorted)                      # <---- shufle again the array
t2 = timeit(lambda: sort_alg2(unsorted), number=1)

print(t1)
print(t2)
```

Prints:

```
0.456114097032696
0.5958397497888654
```

So first function is faster.

Comment: I need to stop coding at 2 in the night, this is the 10th stupid mistake in a week that I have made coding late in the night cause I am deprived of sleep, and I can't code any other time cause I have school. Somebody send me help!

Thanks by the way for helping me!

One thing that is still bothering me though is why is the first one faster. Is it cause creating a new list each time using the map function is too expensive compared to sorting in place using the key argument?

Comment: Also I made a deepcopy of the original shuffled list and ran each of them through one of the sorting functions and I still get the second one to be faster than the first function, though the margins much slimmer but I get these results consistently (happened everytime over 6 runs)

Answer (score 0):

`unsorted.sort` in function `sort_alg1` sorts the list in place so that `sort_alg2` is not starting out with quite the same version of the `unsorted` list. Moreover, once `sort_alg2` executes the statement `l = list(map(int, unsorted))`, `l` is now a completely sorted list if we are sorting by integer values. So `l.sort()` is going to run in trivial time.

Note the `assert` statement in the `sort_alg2` function:

```python
import random

n = 10000000
unsorted = [str(x) for x in range(n)]
random.shuffle(unsorted)

def sort_alg1(unsorted):
    unsorted.sort(key = lambda x: int(x))
    return unsorted

def sort_alg2(unsorted):
    l=list(map(int,unsorted))
    # make a copy of l:
    l2 = l.copy()
    l.sort()
    assert(l == l2) # proof!
    s=list(map(str,l))
    return s

sort_alg1(unsorted)
sort_alg2(unsorted)
```